# Raspberry Pi_SaberTooth 2X12 and simple serial

Tags: pi-3, python, dc-motor

I'm trying to control a SaberTooth 2x12 connected to my Pi3. Based my Google research it seemed the best method was Simple Serial.
 I configured the Pi for Serial in raspi-config. Set the dip switches on the SaberTooth for simple serial and 9600 baud. I added a Level Shifter between the Pi and SaberTooth.

According to the Sabertooth documentation, with simple serial 1-127 controls the speed and direction of M1 and 128-255 speed and direction of M2. "0" shuts the motors off. When I run the code motor1 moves in one direction and one speed and will continue until power is removed.

As long as I'm sending a "number" of any value the same results: Motor 1 one speed and one direction. One thing the original code I was basing this off of use "ser.writeString". When I ran the code with that format it said Serial Object does not have "String".
 Can you advise what I'm doing wrong?

```
#! /user/bin/env python
# _*_ coding : utf-8 _*_

import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600)
def main():
   print("Program Start")
   time.sleep(5)
   x=0
     while x < 4:
       ser.write("M1: 1\r\n")
       ser.write("M2: 128\r\n")
       time.sleep(2)
       ser.write("M1: 64\r\n")
       ser.write("M2: 192\r\n")
       time.sleep(2)
       ser.write("M1: 127\r\n")
       ser.write("M2: 255\r\n")
       time.sleep(2)
       ser.write("M1: 0\r\n")
       ser.write("M2: 0\r\n")
       time.sleep(2)
       x = x + 1

if __name__ == '_main_':
   main()
```

Here's the traceback of the error I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "MotorTest.py", line 27, in <module> main() 
File "MotorTest.py" , line 16 in main 
ser.writeString("M1: 1\r\n") 
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'writeString' 
------------ 
Program exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you include the actual code you were using, in text form, if possible? We discourage images of text, as they can be difficult to read and can't be searched or copied so that we can test the code ourselves. In addition, when you get the error, please copy the *full* message including the stack trace into your post too; that'll help us find the error more quickly.

Comment: Here is the code in text form;

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600)
def main():
  print("Program Start")
  time.sleep(5)
  x=0
    while x < 4:
      ser.write("M1: 1\r\n")
      ser.write("M2: 128\r\n")
      time.sleep(2)
      ser.write("M1: 64\r\n")
      ser.write("M2: 192\r\n")
      time.sleep(2)
      ser.write("M1: 127\r\n")
      ser.write("M2: 255\r\n")
      time.sleep(2)
      ser.write("M1: 0\r\n")
      ser.write("M2: 0\r\n")
      time.sleep(2)
      x = x + 1

if __name__ == '_main__':
   main()

Comment: Best to [edit] with that instead of putting it in a comment, @Brian; the comment formatting interferes with the code and since only one line is supported in comments, it's difficult to read. You can indent with 4 spaces when editing and you'll get clearer code block formatting.

Comment: Ok I edited but I think the formatting got messed up because when I click on the "edit" it looks correct, however looking at it on the "main" screen it looks off. Must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, as I say, indent all code with 4 spaces (I've done this for you now) and the formatting will stay as expected. Do you have the full stack trace as well? (this is the long error message that you get from Python telling you what went wrong; it'll include a line number and some more details which will help us figure out what's going on).

Comment: As mentioned when I run the code as shown I don't get any error messages. Motor1 runs at one speed no direction change. Motor2 doesn't run at all. If I add ser.writeString and run the program I get the following error message;

Comment: " Traceback (most recent call last): File "MotorTest.py", line 27, in <module> main() File "MotorTest.py" , line 16 in main ser.writeString("M1: 1\r\n")  AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'writeString' ------------ Program exited with code: 1) "  That is the entire error message. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I had a little look around and found a [Python library for Sabertooth controllers](https://github.com/MomsFriendlyRobotCompany/pysabertooth); might it be easier to use that instead?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this library.One caution note is when I first ran a program using the library I was getting an error message referring to line 114 in the PySabertooth.py code regarding "self.saber.is_open".

Comment: The error message said Attribute Error: Serial module does not contain "is_open". I went into the PySabertooth.py program and under "def open(self)" I commented the "if not" line and un-indented the next line which is self.saber.open(). Saved, ran my test program and it worked as hoped. The other note is the library allows you to set the baud rateat the beginning. Testing has shown that anything above 9600 baud, there are no error messages, but the motors don't move either. However, presently I can work with the 9600 baud rate.

Comment: Again Thank You pointing me to this Library. For my money my question/problem has been answered!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Aurora001 for pointing me to https://github.com/MomsFriendlyRobotCompany/pysabertooth. Using this library I'm able to get the motor control I wanted. A couple of side notes to add. As mentioned in the comments above, when I used the library as is I got an Attribute Error: Serial module does not include "is_open". I modified the installed PySabertooth.py code by commenting out the "if not self.saber.is_open:" line in the open(self) function. Un-indented the next line "self.saber.open() and my program worked. The second note is for a Pi3 instead of '/dev/tty.usbserial' I used '/dev/serial0'  Thanks again for your help!!